# How to secure floor joists on top of beams

Tags: framing, joists, load-bearing, beam

I can't find how to best connect my floor joists on top of my beams. Everything I'm finding online is about connecting them using hangers with a flush height. This is a 10x16 shed/dry-cabin that I am trying to design on my own without architect/engineer. The beams will either be 4x8x16' or three 2x10x16's nailed together. The joists are 2x10x10's spanning just about 10' plus or minus the few inches of cantilever on each side.

Do I just put a few toenails in each? Do I need simpson ties (hurricane straps or something)? or lag bolts/long decking screws?

Having a heck of a time finding anything in building code or similar examples. This isn't being inspected or permitted so it's a "what's the best reasonable way to secure and be sturdy?"

[image]

Comment: Toe nailing should be enough.  You just need the joists not to move around.  The rim joists plus some blocking in the centre will keep the joists straight/plumb.  Extra need for more anchors will depend if you need them for your local weather.  The joists and beams are to hold weight bearing straight down.

Comment: If there are locations near you that are subject to codes and inspections it would be instructive to look at them.  They usually are there to address local conditions.  If you're not bound by them, you're lucky you can pick and choose but why not exploit the work that was done to create those rules?

Answer (score 3):

Use hurricane ties. As the name suggests, they're meant to keep the building (or, typically, the roof) from being lifted up by a strong wind. They cost about a buck each, which is well worth it. In most places, these would be considered optional, but if you're located somewhere that's prone to tornadoes or hurricanes, I'd say they're mandatory.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Toenailing is traditional (and usually adequate because it prevents the joist from moving sideways), but a few Simpson hurricane ties (H2.5AZ) would provide cheap insurance.

If you’re really concerned about uplift, strapping each corner would improve things.